# Prove that dimension of solution of linear equation $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = 0$. ($\exists a_i \not= 0$) is $n - 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have already seen question like this here. But I don't know the theory that was applied in there in order to show that.

I was given a hint that I could consider such linear map $A$ that does this: $$A(X) = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 + \cdots + a_nx_n$$

$X$ is basically column with these $x$s. After that I should somehow apply the fact that $\dim \ker A + \dim \operatorname{im} A = \dim V$ where $V$ is vector space which vectors $A$ takes as a parameters.

Could you, please, explain how can I use it in order to prove that dimension of solution is $n - 1$?

Comment: What is in the title is not an equation. Do you miss something?

Comment: @mrsamy Thank you for noticing. Edited

Comment: Here's an intuitive hint: In order to solve the equation above, you have $n-1$ degree of freedom. You can arbitrarily set $n-1$ of the variables to some values but the remaining $x_n$ (or whatever is remaining) is determined by the $n-1$ variables you have set.

Comment: @crystal_math Thanks! I uderstand its intuitive part. However, I am not sure how to formally prove that. Or it is formal enough?

Comment: Well a solution for your equation is $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}, -\dfrac{a_1x_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}x_{n-1}}{a_n})$ which is in a span of $n-1$ eigenvectors (think about how to prove this at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

The $1$-by-$n$ matrix $A=[a_1 \cdots a_n]$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

The image of $A$ is of dimension $1$ since there exists $a_i\ne 0$. Also $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of dimension $n$.

Now you can apply the rank-nullity theorem.